# rows of columns to column

Tags: python, pandas

Would I need to use pivot to make a row of columns into one column? I have a dataset like the one shown but within each row are 8 separate rows. I need to make each cell its own row.

This would be an example of what i would start with:

```
d = {'col1':[1,9,17],'col2':[2,10,18],'col3':[3,11,19],'col4':[4,12,20],'col5':[5,13,21],'col6':[6,14,22],'col7':[7,15,23],'col8':[8,16,24]}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And then would need to have a new df like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

Comment: Do you want to convert `df` into your desired output or `d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using `melt()`

```
df1=df.melt().drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values('value')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stack the dataframe vertically:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'col': df.stack().values})
```

or using the underlying *raw* array (`.to_numpy().ravel()`/`.to_numpy().flatten()`):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'col': df.to_numpy().flatten()})
```

---

```
print(new_df)
```

---

```
    col
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
7     8
8     9
9    10
10   11
11   12
12   13
13   14
14   15
15   16
16   17
17   18
18   19
19   20
20   21
21   22
22   23
23   24
```

Comment: If you use the underlying numpy array, directly go for `df.to_numpy().ravel()` ;)

Comment: @mozway, or `df.to_numpy().flatten()` , thanks